# save_model method, but database wants different relations?

Tags: python, django, user-controls, django-admin

When I try to update user data, I get this error: Database is trying to update a relational field of type CharField with a value of type User. Make sure you are setting the correct relations.

This is my views.py:

```
def settings(request):
title = "Account Settings"
form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        m = form.save(commit=False)
        m.username = request.user
        m.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home.html')
else:
    form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user)

context = {
    'title': title,
    'form': form
}
template = 'settings.html'
return render(request, template, context)
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), max_length=30, required=True)
last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), max_length=30, required=True)
email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), max_length=75, required=True)
# company = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), max_length=50, required=False)
# url = forms.URLField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), max_length=100, required=False)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email',]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m.username = request.user
```

is where the problem is, it should be:

```
m.username = request.user.username
```